# GUI building trouble

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have a GUI setup that looks like this:

[image: example]

It displays a document and enables user to edit it by adding/removing `JTextAreas` and text in them.

I have a problem when trying to open the document. Document itself is made up of layers of `JPanels` on top of each other. There are never more than 6 layers of `JPanels` at a single point in the GUI.

Since I don't know what the height of the `JTextArea` will be, I have to make it relative to the parent (in other words, not specify it).

Because the layout manager (`MigLayout`) doesn't know the exact size of the component (it's relative to the parent), it first asks its parent for the parent's size. That size is again unknown and the parent's parent is asked and so on (until a level 1 or 2 JPanel). In the end it has to ask a lot of components for their size (a method `checkParent(Container)` within MigLayout was called over 100 000 times just for the example above).

What I need to do is set the height of the `JTextArea` (or the `JPanel` that it resides in) only when the document is being opened, so the layout manager doesn't have to ask `JTextAreas` parent, causing a recursive hell.

After the document is opened I have to reset the height to default (so the height adjusts when the text is added/removed).

I have absolutley no idea how to do this, or if this is the way to go, I'm only sure that the thing I described above is the problem.

Several notes:

- this is not a `MigLayout` bug, I have been to the forums(link below)
- [check this out (the last post)](http://migcalendar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12263&sid=9398dd7e8c8cf5e42b48572d56a87bae)
- I can't put a `JScrollPane` into the `JTextArea` as its task isn't only to hold the information, but to display exactly how much room it takes
- I can easily get the heights of the `JTextAreas` when saving the document, thus having them at my disposal when opening it again

**EDIT:
The document referenced in this question is not "the document" as thingy used in JTextAreas and similar, but "a document" as in custom class in my program (which I didn't mention because it is irrelevant, unless it's understood as "the document").**

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Document` models a hierarchical structure, you need a tree. Because your interface requires both a control and a view for each node, you need a table. `Outline`, seen [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692), might be a suitable choice. Your `DocumentTreeModel` would hold a reference to the document's root `Element`, just as the example's `FileTreeModel` holds a reference to the root `File`. Your `RowModel` would include a `JLabel`, a `JCheckBox` and a `JTextArea`.

Comment: I need the apperance of my program to be exactly the same as the one in the picture attached, so this wouldn't really work...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of an existing `Document` view that comes closer.

Comment: I'm not neccessarily looking for an alternative view, as much as I'm looking for a solution to GUI recursive resizing problem...